# Fade portion of image with image banner after 20 seconds

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow, fade

I have rotating back ground image after 20 seconds with the fadeIn and fadeOut.
Images contain logo at the top-left corner and person image at right side top to bottom now the problem is image should be rotated with fadeIn and fadeOut but logo at the top left corner should not have effect of fadeIn and fadeOut(should not have effect of changing).

so my question is how to fade only portion of the one background image and other portion should not have faded(or not looking)

### My current working jquery code

```
    $("DIV#background IMG").eq(0).fadeIn(1000, function(){
        setTimeout("changeBackground(0)",20000);
    });

    changeBackground = function (i){
        curr_index = i;
        //alert(curr_index);
        nex_index = ((i + 1) > 3 ) ? 0 : i + 1;
        //alert(nex_index); 
        $("DIV#background IMG").fadeOut(1000)
        $("DIV#background IMG").eq(nex_index).fadeIn(1000, function(){
            setTimeout("changeBackground(nex_index)",20000);
        });
    }
```

**note:** above code is correct and working successfully

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a jquery plugin for cycling images. [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).
Put all images in the same container element and call `cycle()` on it.

The plugin fades one image directly on top of the other, so if the logo part of your images stays allways in the same place, you won't notice it's fading.

Another idea would be to put your logo in a separate (transparent .png) image and style it with `position:absolute` to the right location on top of your rotating images.

Comment: Thanks I try jQuery cycle plugin but It still fade the logo so I choose second option It solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add jQuery plugin [jquery-rotate](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/). Then you can use:

```
.rotate(angle,[whence=relative])
.rotateLeft([angle=90])
.rotateRight([angle=90])
```

In your code:

```
$("DIV#background IMG").fadeOut(1000).rotateRight([angle=360])
```

Moreover, your code lacks a `;` in the end of the second line.

If your concept of `rotate` is as in **Banner Rotater**, then this is the code.

```
$("DIV#background IMG").fadeOut(1000).attr('src', 'newimage.png').fadeIn(1000);
```

Or better having the time as a variable so that you can change at anytime between the slides:

```
var time = 500; // Keeping it 500 because of 500 (fadeIn) + 500 (fadeOut) = 1000!
$("DIV#background IMG").fadeOut(time).attr('src', 'newimage.png').fadeIn(time);
```

## Full Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Banner Rotate</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function changeBG()
            {
                var d = new Date();
                $(".background img").fadeOut(500).attr('src', 'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/?' + d.getMilliseconds()).fadeIn(500);
            }
            $(document).ready(function(){
                setInterval('changeBG()', 1500);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="background">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" alt="" />
        </div>
        <a href="#" onclick="changeBG(); return false;">Change</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for reply but My meaning of rotate is just change the image no.1 to image no.2 after 20 secons with the fade in effect.

Comment: Updated the code. Sorry for misunderstanding. :) Try this `$("DIV#background IMG").fadeOut(1000).attr('src', 'newimage.png').fadeIn(1000);`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have successfully fadeout and fadein image with the rotation(banner rotation) with the above posted my code but problem is when image in faded the portion of image at top left corner should not faded which is logo so main part is how to make this happen in one image where one portion should faded and another portion should not faded with jquery or css anything.I hope now my problem is more clear to you and sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: thanks for answer but it did not work whole image is fadding but I want only right part of image looks fadding. logo at the left side shold not look faded.